# Renaming a file on Docker build does not persist

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have this simple docker file:

```
FROM richarvey/nginx-php-fpm

RUN mv /var/www/html/index.php /var/www/html/info.php

ADD dist/ /var/www/html/
```

And i build it with this command:

```
docker build -t mydockerimage .
```

But when I check, the `/var/www/html/index.php` is still there but what I intended to do was rename in into `/var/www/html/info.php`.

I am also clearing my cached images every time I rebuild the image.

Can someone please point me out why is it like that?

EDIT #1

```
time="2017-04-25T22:01:48+08:00" level=info msg="Unable to use system certificate pool: crypto/x509: system root pool is not avail
able on Windows"
Sending build context to Docker daemon 89.73 MB
Step 1/3 : FROM richarvey/nginx-php-fpm
 ---> d1db840b1d7d
Step 2/3 : RUN mv /var/www/html/index.php /var/www/html/info.php
 ---> Running in ca7db6008c64
 ---> 203246f59783
Removing intermediate container ca7db6008c64
Step 3/3 : ADD dist/ /var/www/html/
 ---> 4dcb74384b35
Removing intermediate container 0c99b349e9c0
Successfully built 4dcb74384b35
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added
to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files a
nd directories.
```

Comment: post the messages on `docker build --no-cache -t mydockerimage .` and `docker history mydockerimage` in order to `docker run -it layer_after_RUN_mv bash`  and check what you find

Comment: run the docker history and did `docker run --rm -it 4dcb74384b35 bash` but it is still named `index.php` instead of `info.php`

Comment: no, use `docker run -it 203246f59783 bash` just after the mv

Comment: did that, same result.

Comment: try `docker run --rm -it richarvey/nginx-php-fpm bash` and check if you get a message issuing `mv /var/www/html/index.php /var/www/html/info.php`

Comment: the `mv` command worked as intended.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142630/discussion-between-user2915097-and-alisongaleon).